# How can I create a new spreadsheet file using the OOXML SDK that contains multiple worksheets?

Tags: c#, excel-2007

I downloaded the OOXML SDK. I need to create a simple Excel spreadsheet that has x worksheets, each with 4 columns and y rows of data. It's pretty simple, but I can't find an example of how to create sheets anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

According to the MSDN article [How to: Insert a New Worksheet into a Spreadsheet Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc881781.aspx), you should be able to add a worksheet to a spreadsheet by adding a `WorksheetPart` to a `SpreadsheetDocument`, then getting the first child of type `Sheets` on the associated `Workbook` and appending a new `Sheet` instance to it.